# Pyodbc utf-8 bind param error With FreeTDS and unixODBC

Tags: unicode, odbc, pyodbc, freetds

FreeTDS version 0.82

unixODBC version 2.3.0

pyodbc version 2.1.8

freetds.conf:

```
tds version = 7.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

using Servername in the odbc.ini (which for some crazed reason made a difference in getting unixODBC to recognize the client charset in freetds)

I'm able to pull utf8 data correctly and can update with the string inline ie:

```
UPDATE table
SET col = N'私はトカイ大好き'
WHERE id = 182333369
```

But

```
text = u'私はトカイ大好き'

cursor.execute("""
    UPDATE table
    SET column = ?
    WHERE id = 182333369 
""", text)
```

Fails with:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]
Invalid data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

If I add:

```
text = text.encode('utf-8')
```

I get the following error:

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The stream ended unexpectedly. (4002) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Any ideas as to where things have gone astray?

Comment: I have the same problem, using Ubuntu 11.04 versions of freetds, pyodbc

Answer (score 1):

Unicode support was reworked in pyodbc 3.0.x.  Try testing with the latest source (3.0.2-beta02, etc.)